# Restrict typeform to single submission on Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, cookies, typeform

Have a simple typeform embedded into a post in Wordpress. Nothing fancy at all. Embed code pulled direct from Typeform.

However, people can submit multiple times. ie. One person could theoretically do it 100 times.

Typeform have advised a cookie will solve this, and restrict a user to a single submission - but really do not know where to begin there. Is there a simple, quick fix that could do such a thing? Any ideas completely welcome!

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions could be only showing the embedded typeform if the cookie does not exist.

not really sure how you would do this in Wordpress.

But the logic is:

```js
const embedElement = document.querySelector('.target-dom-node') 
const displayed = getCookie("displayed_typeform");
if (displayed){
  embedElement.innerHTML="<h2>Typeform already displayed once.</h2>"
} else if(!displayed && displayed === "") {
  setCookie("displayed_typeform", true, 365);
  showEmbed();
}
```

`setCookie` and `getCookie` are two functions that deal with cookie management

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) { 
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can find a complete project that demonstrates this feature [here](https://glitch.com/%7Etf-embed-cookies).